# Is it possible to disable weekends from Sharpeoint Datepicker field

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, javascript, datepicker

Is there an option to disable the weekends in default Sharepoint Datepicker field, I was able to disable the past days with the help of the below URL:

[How to disable previous date in a calendar in sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/274651/how-to-disable-previous-date-in-a-calendar-in-sharepoint)

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? This is not possible using SharePoint OOB capabilities. you need to customize the list form to achieve this/

Comment: i'm using Sharepoint 2013 version, and trying to disable the weekends options in the new item form, can u pls elaborate how i can achieve this through Javascript/Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Disable saturday and sunday in datepicker for your reference:

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1235140/Disable-saturday-and-sunder-in-datepicker

https://forums.asp.net/t/1995852.aspx?How+to+disable+Saturday+and+Sundays+in+Datepicker+using+Jquery+or+JavaScript+

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the weekends in Datepicker using JQuery.

You need to add custom script using script editor/content editor webpart on your list form.

JQuery code to disable weekends:

```
$(".selector").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends }
```

Here you need to use the selector specific to your date field.

**Reference**:

[Can the jQuery UI Datepicker be made to disable Saturdays and Sundays (and holidays)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holid)